# iOS Swift button text do not change on click

Tags: ios, swift

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonText: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.


    }
    @IBAction func btnButtonACTION(sender: UIButton) {
        buttonText.setTitle("changetext", forState: .Normal)

    }
}
```

I trying to learn the basics of swift language through Xcode. The idea is to change the button text when I click it. But it doesn`t change. Is there anything that I missed?

Comment: Try `sender.setTitle("changetext", forState: .Normal)` instead.

Comment: Did you hook up the outlet as well as the action?

Comment: If the button weren't hooked up, it would be crashing, not silently failing.

Answer (score 0):

You are using:

```
buttonText.setTitle("changetext", forState: .Normal)
```

Try this:

```
buttonText.setTitle("changetext", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change text on click of the button, then you must connect button to the send action
[image]